# Elastic Beanstalk CORS Configuration for Post Request

Tags: tomcat, configuration, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, preflight

I receive the following error when submitting a post request from my localhost -

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sample-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/resource 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access
```

But, in the CORS configuration editor for my S3 instance, I have the following -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

I've played around with these three lines, but I'm still unable to diagnose the problem.

```
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
```

My developer console shows the following headers, which makes me think this CORS configuration isn't even being read -

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 21 Apr 2017 02:48:01 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Does anyone see something wrong with my configurations or is there something else that must be added? I was able to add CORS filter to the web.xml of my tomcat and everything worked fine so I think I am configuring my elastic beanstalk incorrectly.

EDIT

Added the following .config file (formerly, .yaml)

add_cors.config.config

```
files:
"/etc/httpd/conf.d/cors.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        <Location "/">
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
            Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept"
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

            SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        </Location>
```

And it is in this location in the exploded war -

```
.
├── app.war
├── .ebextensions
│   ├── add_cors.config.yaml
├── META-INF
│   ├── …
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   └── …
    ├── servlet.xml
    ├── lib
    │   ├── …
    └── web.xml
```

I re-deployed the war, but I'm still having the same error - "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"

SOLUTION

No .ebextensions files were necessary. I just needed to add the CORS filters to the web.xml like I had in my tomcat's conf/web.xml

```
  <!-- ================== CORS FILTERS ===================== -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
      <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: How can I access and edit the web.xml file? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about AWS EB, but assuming there is an apache reverse proxy in front of tomcat, it looks like you can use ebextensions and add the CORS header info there. See this:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=570570

and

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding a cors configuration file, but I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: Try changing the file extension to .config (remove .yaml) as per the documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Then redeploy.

Comment: Also, double check the indentation in your yaml file very closely. It looks like it's missing quite a bit of indentation based on what you pasted above.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the extension and added the proper indentation, but it still returned the same error. Just adding the CORS filters to the web.xml resolved the issue